# Provide file for easily editing text (to be used for email)

Tags: power-automate

My flow involves creating folders, sharing them with specific people, and then sending a success email to the person who initiated the folder creation.

I am able to do all of this successfully, but where I am running into a problem is that I would like to allow colleagues to edit the text that will be sent in the email easily (i.e. not have to go into PA). I was thinking I'd create a text file in Sharepoint and 'Get file content' to use the text of that file as the email. I copied and pasted the text from inside PA to a .txt file. It works, except my dynamic content does not display correctly. It displays like '@{outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r6f35ec2d1175k4kkd']} ' (how it looks when I pasted it in the txt).

Has anyone ever created a 'template' to allow users to edit text used in a flow, while also containing dynamic content? Any tips for doing so?